# Intellisense with modules required from electronjs with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, intellisense

Small but annoying issue, im working with electron and react, and when I access the 'fs' module it works, but there's no intellisense whatsoever.

for example:

`import fs from 'fs' or const fs = require('fs')`

will provide the proper methods and autocompletion,

but:

`const electronFs = window.require('electron').remote.require('fs')`
will not.

I know why it's happening, but I wonder if there is any way to provide the same intellisense to the fs module exported from electron?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention explicit definitions to VS Code Intellisense so, you need to write
`const electronFs: typeof import('fs') = window.require('electron').remote.require('fs')`

Now, `electronFs.` will give you suggestions